# How do i convert String into list of integers in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell

I have a `String` like `"1 2 3 4 5"`. How can I convert it into a list of integers like `[1,2,3,4,5]` in Haskell? What if the list is `"12345"`?

Comment: -1, Can you add the code you have tried with?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use

```
Prelude> map read $ words "1 2 3 4 5" :: [Int]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Here we use `words` to split `"1 2 3 4 5"` on whitespace so that we get `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`. The `read` function can now convert the individual strings into integers. It has type `Read a => String -> a` so it can actually convert to anything in the `Read` type class, and that includes `Int`. It is because of the type variable in the return type that we need to specify the type above.

For the string without spaces, we need to convert each `Char` into a single-element list. This can be done by applying `(:"")` to it — a `String` is just a list of `Char`s. We then apply `read` again like before:

```
Prelude> map (read . (:"")) "12345" :: [Int]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
q1 :: Integral a => String -> [a]
q1 = map read . words

q2 :: Integral a => String -> [a]
q2 = map (read . return)
```

Error handling is left as an exercise. (Hint: you will need a different return type.)

Comment: I think you mean q2 = .. not q2 ::

Comment: So, in the second case, q2, `return` will pick up a single Char, say '1', and return it in the context of a String (to be fed to `read` which expects one)? So, it is returned in a general "context", which we specify at the end as context of a list (of Ints)? Kinda makes sense. I have to start thinking more in this kind of way. So, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a function defined in the module [Data.Char](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html) called [digitToInt](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:digitToInt). It takes a character and returns a number, as long as the character could be interpreted as an hexadecimal digit.

If you want to use this function in your first example, where the numbers where separated by a space, you'll need to avoid the spaces. You can do that with a simple filter

```
> map digitToInt $ filter (/=' ') "1 2 1 2 1 2 1"
[1,2,1,2,1,2,1]
```

The second example, where the digits where not separated at all, is even easier because you don't need a filter

```
> map digitToInt "1212121"
[1,2,1,2,1,2,1]
```

I'd guess *digitToInt* is better than *read* because it doesn't depend on the type of the expression, which could be tricky (which is in turn how i found this post =P ). Anyway, I'm new to haskell so i might as well be wrong =).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
> [read [x] :: Int | x <- string]
```

Comment: Simple, sort and easy to remember. Just how I like them. Or, differently, `map (\x -> read [x] :: Int) string`